# How to wait for 2 actions and join their results in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux, saga, redux-saga

in my application I'd like to define a saga that will handle either `LEFT_CHANGED` or `RIGHT_CHANGED` actions and continue with new action `SOURCES_CHANGED` with payload consisting of payloads of the aforementioned actions.

```
export function* watchLeftRightChanged() {  
  const left = null;
  const right = null;
  while (true) {
    const result = yield take(['LEFT_CHANGED', 'RIGHT_CHANGED'])
    switch (result.type) {
      case 'LEFT_CHANGED':
        yield put({ type: 'SOURCES_CHANGED', result, right })
        continue;
      case 'RIGHT_CHANGED':
        yield put({ type: 'SOURCES_CHANGED', left, result })
        continue
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `left` and `right` variables are `null` when `SOURCES_CHANGED` action is emitted and their value is not maintained (I believe dut to the nature of the iterator).

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: You never assign left nor right, that's why they are undefined.

Comment: Ooops, you're right! Thanks